# How to write CanCanCan Ability for user to read only their data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, cancancan

How do you restrict user access so a user can only read their own record?

I've tried:

```
def initialize(user)
  can :read, User, :id => user.id
```

and this:

```
def initialize(user)
  can :read, user
```

but I can still access every user in index and show. I have authorize_resource in the UsersController.

Relevant documentation for reference:
https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that putting

```
authorize! :show, @user
```

in the show action and

```
@users = User.accessible_by(current_ability)
```

in the index action solves my issue using:

```
def initialize(user)
  can :read, User, :id => user.id
```

I can now see I should have been using load_and_authorize_resource instead of just authorize_resource as it would have automatically added those.

Answer (score 1):

```
:read != :show

:read == [:show, :index]
```

Unfortunately I don't have a setup to test it so its a shot in the dark.

```
can :show, User, :id => user.id
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm still able to show another user's page with this unfortunately